# How to stream a large file to S3 using Amplify

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I need to upload large video files from my React Native app to S3 using the Amplify library. I've been unable to find any example of how to do this using streams. Right now I'm able to read the file using rn-fetch-blob, then `put` it to S3, but I'd like to use a stream instead. I don't understand how to convert this to a stream approach.

```
const blob = await RNFetchBlob.fs
  .readFile(localurl, "base64")
  .then(data => Buffer.from(data, "base64"));

Storage.put(my-video.mp4, blob, {
  contentType,
  bucket
});
```

Is this possible with Amplify, and if so can you provide an example? I'd rather avoid importing the entire AWS SDK for this.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar I did not and am still using PUT.

Comment: I think so you can create a stream and write data into the state by showing percentage of data done and then upload it to s3 bucket

Comment: Here is one solution which I built & tried.
https://dev.to/walvekarnikhil/reactnative-large-file-upload-using-amplify-s3-17ho